# How to prevent that the password to decrypt the private key has to be entered every time when using Git Bash on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, passwords, ssh-keys

I've an automatic building service which download from a git private repository.
The problem is that when it tries to clone repository it need to provide the password, because it is not remembered; so because there is no human interaction, it waits forever the password.
How can I force it to remember from id_rsa.pub?

Answer (score 264):

For Windows users, just a note that this is how I set up the Git Bash environment to log me in *once* when I start it up. I edit my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```

So when I start Git Bash, it looks like:

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.7.8-preview20111206)
(etc)
Agent pid 3376
Enter passphrase for /c/Users/starmonkey/.ssh/id_dsa:
Identity added: /c/Users/starmonkey/.ssh/id_dsa (/c/Users/starmonkey/.ssh/id_dsa)
```

And now I can ssh to other servers without logging in every time.

Comment: If you don't have a ~/.bashrc file then just create a new text file (notepad or some other editor) and add the two lines starmonkey mentioned.

Comment: '~' refers to your "home directory". In Windows, you can find this by opening a command shell (cmd) and typing "echo %USERPROFILE%".

Comment: For me this syntax is not working. I had to write `eval $(ssh-agent)` instead.

Comment: Everything's ok but now I have to type my passphrase + every git command I have to type password for server's shell connection. Generally - not working.

Comment: My issue was that I needed to specify the file for ssh-add to use. Probably because I have more than one and wasn't using the default name. Example `ssh-add ~/.ssh/myfile_rsa`

Comment: Works great. Using @versedi's comment, I was able to add multiple keys, by adding multiple lines of `ssh-add /<drive_letter>/path/to/mykey_rsa`.

Comment: nice ! I was looking for a while to cache my passphrase on windows, now its done, THX :)

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I took the route similar to *clash* and used `eval $('ssh-agent')` then `ssh-add` then gave it my password and now I'm not asked for my password anymore.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Stephen Tun Aung's answer to use credential.helper wincred does work.

Comment: `copy > ~/.bashrc` in git bash to create the bashrc file in windows, ignore the error

Comment: The instructions works pretty fine for me in Windows 7 and git bash. The only detail is that I needed to change the `bash.bashrc` file in the installation directory - in my case `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\bash.bashrc`

Comment: Not sure if there are anyway to save the pass phrases after exit/re-open the git bash (Windows 10). There are a tons of guide about SSH Key, but no one resolve the pass phrases still ask everytime open git bash, it's quite annoyance.

Answer (score 62):

**This answer explains how to get the GitHub username and password to be stored permanently, not the SSH key passphrase.**

In Windows, just run

```
$ git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

This means that the next time you push, you'll enter your username and password as usual, but they'll be saved in Windows credentials. You won't have to enter them again, after that.

As in, *[Push to GitHub without entering username and password every time (Git Bash on Windows)](http://www.tilcode.com/push-github-without-entering-username-password-windows-git-bash/)*.

Comment: after this command you need to type your user name and password.

Comment: Does this pertain to SSH keys, or only HTTPS (username & password) authentication?  The question appears to be about using SSH keys.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, I guess I am using HTTPS (username & password) authentication.

Comment: Running this produced no output at all.

Comment: @user9993 It won't. It's a configuration change, so while no output will be made, `git` will change its behaviour according to the configuration directive set.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer not to have to type my SSH passphrase when opening new terminals; unfortunately [starmonkey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727555/how-to-prevent-that-the-password-to-decrypt-the-private-key-has-to-be-entered-ev/9011152#9011152) requires the password to be typed in for every session. Instead, I have this in my `.bash_profile` file:

```
# Note: ~/.ssh/environment should not be used, as it
#       already has a different purpose in SSH.

env=~/.ssh/agent.env

# Note: Don't bother checking SSH_AGENT_PID. It's not used
#       by SSH itself, and it might even be incorrect
#       (for example, when using agent-forwarding over SSH).

agent_is_running() {
    if [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
        # ssh-add returns:
        #   0 = agent running, has keys
        #   1 = agent running, no keys
        #   2 = agent not running
        ssh-add -l >/dev/null 2>&1 || [ $? -eq 1 ]
    else
        false
    fi
}

agent_has_keys() {
    ssh-add -l >/dev/null 2>&1
}

agent_load_env() {
    . "$env" >/dev/null
}

agent_start() {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >"$env")
    . "$env" >/dev/null
}

if ! agent_is_running; then
    agent_load_env
fi

# If your keys are not stored in ~/.ssh/id_rsa or ~/.ssh/id_dsa, you'll need
# to paste the proper path after ssh-add
if ! agent_is_running; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif ! agent_has_keys; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

This will remember my passphrase for new terminal sessions as well; I only have to type it in once when I open my first terminal after booting.

I'd like to credit where I got this; it's a modification of somebody else's work, but I can't remember where it came from. Thanks anonymous author!

**Update 2019-07-01:** I don't think all this is necessary. I now consistently have this working by ensuring my `.bash_profile` file runs the ssh-agent:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Then I set up an `ssh` configuration file like this:

```
touch ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
echo 'AddKeysToAgent yes' >> ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: I still get asked for my passphrase every time.

Comment: @Ryan hopefully the update I've just added will address your problem.  I keep the info up to date in a blog post at http://conan.is/blogging/clojure-on-windows.html, and I asked the same question myself at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423626/remember-git-passphrase-in-wsl

Comment: @Conan The updated solution work per bash session. After I close my running bash session and opened a new one, I was again prompted for entering password.

Comment: The updated solution launches a new instance of the ssh-agent every time a new Git Bash is opened.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question correctly, you're already using an authorized SSH key in the build service, but you want to avoid having to type the passphrase for every clone?

I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. If your build service is being started interactively: Before you start the build service, start `ssh-agent` with a sufficiently long timeout (`-t` option). Then use `ssh-add` (msysGit should have those) to add all the private keys you need before you start your build service. You'd still have to type out all the passphrases, but only once per service launch.
2. If you want to avoid having to type the passphrases out at all, you can always remove the passphrases from the SSH keys, as described in *https://serverfault.com/questions/50775/how-do-i-change-my-private-key-passphrase*, by setting an empty new passphrase. This should do away with the password prompt entirely, but it is even less secure than the previous option.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to push my code, I got the below error:

```
$ git push origin dev

remote: Too many invalid password attempts. Try logging in through the website with your password.
fatal: unable to access 'https://naushadqamar-1@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx-api.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

After a few hours of research, I found I need to use the below command:

```
$ git config --global credential.helper cache
```

After executing the above command, I got the prompt for entering my GitHub username and password. After providing the correct credentials, I am able to push my code.

Comment: This just generated "git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command."  However "git config --global credential.helper store" worked - this may not be the best, but I'm forced to use HTTPS rather than my preferred SSH and just want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is:

1. Run the Windows default terminal - cmd and get the directory of your master profile

   ```
   echo %USERPROFILE%
   ```
2. Run Git Bash in the directory above and create the `.bashrc` file with the command

   ```
   echo "" > .bashrc
   ```
3. Open the `.bashrc` file with your favourite text editor and paste [code from GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/#platform-windows) into that file:

   ```
   env=~/.ssh/agent.env
   ...
   COPY WHOLE CODE FROM URL - I can't add it to Stack Overflow because it breaks layout... OMG!
   ```
4. Restart Git Bash and it asks you for your password (only first time) and done. No password bothering again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the `authorized_keys` file under the `.ssh` folder of the user under which you are going to connect to the repository server. For example, assuming you use username `buildservice` on `repo.server` you can run:

```
cd ~buidservice
mkdir ./ssh
cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then you have to check the following things:

1. That corresponding `id_rsa` private key is presented in `builservice@build.server:~/.shh/id_rsa`.
2. That fingerprint of repo.server is stored in the `buildservice@build.server:~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. Typically that will be done after the first attempt of `ssh` to connect to the `repo.server`.

Comment: I forget to say. Under Windows you home directory probably would be C:\Users\Username

Comment: Mmm.. Git bash has it all, read more carefully title of the question. Also from question I assumed that key-pair has been already generated (because it was asked how to force repo server to remember id_rsa.pub.) Sorry about formatting.

Comment: Ok, never heard of 'git bash' before. Sorry 'bout that

Comment: I'm assuming this is using msysgit. I'm adding the tag.

Comment: Warning! Using `cat id_rsa.pub > .ssh/authorized_keys` will overwrite any existing authorized keys. Use `>>` to add instead of overwrite.