# How to setup ssh key to bypass git bash password prompt

Tags: git, repository, ssh-keys, password-prompt

I would like to disable the password prompt of git, so I thought that I can setup a ssh-key onto my remote repository. But how do I associate it with git on my computer.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remember Password, Git bash under windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727555/remember-password-git-bash-under-windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should only ask for a password if you access git through SSH using a password-protected private key.
If that is the case, you need to run an SSH agent, as described in "[Remember Password, Git bash under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727555/remember-password-git-bash-under-windows)".

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to gitolite: http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite. There is everything in you need and also explained how to setup. A password less login is also possible for CI server for example.

My experience tells me not to use something else, because a self made solution is too cumbersome.

Comment: The OP didn't specifically mention about setting up their own repository - just pushing to a remote one.

Comment: He speaks about a "my remote repository" and I think, that is what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "start-ssh-agent.cmd" on windows which will use ssh key to authenticate. This can be found in "GIT/cmd" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Very detailed instructions can be found on the GitHub website at [Win-Set-Up-Git](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/).  GitHub has an interest in making sure those instructions are good; if they are not, let them know as they will want to improve them.