# Ssh keeps forgetting the keys

Tags: git, github, ssh

This is the problem: I use Git Shell installed with GitHub for Windows. 
I have 3 ssh keys inside `C:\Users\MyName\.ssh`:

- github_rsa (this is the key generated by github for windows)
- id_rsa (generated by me)
- tm_rsa (generated by me)

I inserted the key with this command:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-add ~/.ssh/tm_rsa
```

Everytime I reboot the computer, ssh keeps forgetting the keys. if i do this command `ssh-add -L`, it shows only one key, usually `github_rsa`.

How can I avoid having to enter the keys each time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have to add it to your git bash shell, in .bashrc

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```

Comment: actually, there is a post that says this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727555/remember-password-git-bash-under-windows

Comment: I have created `~/.bashrc` and added those two lines, but nothing is changed. If i restart the pc the problem persist. Do I need to do something more?
*edit* If I try those commands from Git Shell, the command eval is not recognised.

Comment: From the options of GitHub for Windows I have changed the default shell from "PowerShell" to "Git Bash".
Now when I run the Git Bash it ask for the passphrase of id_rsa, but not for the other two keys. And if I close and re-open the Git Bash, it still doesn't remember the keys.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Don't even need to restart windows the bash shell will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ ssh-add -L
The agent has no identities.
```

If you see this message, just run `ssh-add`.

Here's the source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39616339/2941404

Answer (score 0):

First add your private key via ssh-add:

```sh
ssh-add /path-to-private-key
```

then enter the passphrase.

and then run: `ssh-add`

if You've already lost connection, I mean `ssh-add` has no identities, and then you run `ssh-add`, it will not work.
To make it work you have to do all the process in one session.

To automate that just add this line to your `.bashrc` file:

```sh
ssh-add -L || ssh-add /path-to-private-key;ssh-add;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

this one works per session. It kills the ssh-agent after leaving the ssh session, for example from vscode.

The following one runs the ssh-agent in the background and won't kill the agent after leaving the ssh session.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Then just simply add your generated key

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<keyfile>
```