# How to make Git not ask me for password when accessing remote repositories?

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I've been looking at a few different SO posts and other forums for an explanation of how to prevent git from constantly asking for my password whenever I interact with my remote repository, but all I understood was that I need to create ssh key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I store a password for my key so I can commit and pull from repository when using git on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625148/how-do-i-store-a-password-for-my-key-so-i-can-commit-and-pull-from-repository-wh)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to make your private key more secure, a passphrase is used to encrypt it. You can actually ***use `ssh-agent` to store your passphrase once for a terminal/console session, so you don't have to keep entering it all the time***.

You'll need to use `` eval `ssh-agent -s` `` to start the agent, ssh-add to enter your passphrase for your private key, and then `ssh-agent -k` to kill the agent when you're done. It even comes with a timeout, `ssh-add -t <timeout>`, where `<timeout>` can be something like `Xh` for X hours, `Xm` for X minutes, and so on.

`ssh-agent` is available on msysGit and Cygwin. I'm not sure about its availability on other platforms like Unix/Linux/*nix systems and Apple OSX.

You can read more about `ssh-agent` usage from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625148/how-do-i-store-a-password-for-my-key-so-i-can-commit-and-pull-from-repository-wh/3628224#3628224) and [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727555/remember-password-git-bash-under-windows/9011152#9011152), as well as googling around for instructions online.

Answer (score 7):

Create an SSH Key but don't enter a passphrase when it asks you to

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

^ In step two of that article just press enter when it asks for a password

Comment: See! I am just an idiot. I couldn't even google something so simple. That is perfect and I'm on my way to a solution. Thank you! I'm using bitbucket, so here is a link for anyone in the same boat: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Comment: Is each public key (I'm assuming that's the `.pub`) inclusive? As in, do I need a unique `.pub` for each remote repository I have (3 if I have bitbucket, github and heroku repositories)?

Comment: Not sure about bitbucket but with github, the ssh key is linked to your account, so any repository your account has access to, your ssh keys have access to

Comment: @RileyE if you want to make your private key more secure, a passphrase is used to encrypt it. You can actually use `ssh-agent` to store your passphrase once for a terminal/console session, so you don't have to keep entering it all the time. You'll need to use `eval \`ssh-agent -s\`` to start the agent, `ssh-add` to enter your passphrase for your private key, and then `ssh-agent -k` to kill the agent when you're done.

Comment: @Cupcake Does the `ssh-agent` also have a timeout, or is it solely based on the terminal session and `ssh-agent -k`? But that is really good to know, since having a passphrase is much better, but it would be the same as having to put my HTTPS password in every time (before `ssh-agent`).

Comment: @RileyE you can set a timeout like this: `ssh-add -t <timeout>`, where `<timeout>` can be something like `Xh` for X hours, `Xm` for X minutes, and so on.

Comment: @Cupcake Okay. That's quite helpful. So, would `ssh-add -t 8h30m` be a valid timeout request?

Comment: @RileyE yes, that is valid.